# Media Codec - YUV_YV12 to YUV420SP/NV21

Tags: android, opencv, encoding, android-mediacodec

I'm trying to develop an android application that encodes opencv array of Mats of resolution 1200x1200 4 channel images to a mp4 video using Android media codec. The problem I'm facing is that, when I'm trying to use emulator(which uses YUV420P color format - I'm using OpenCV COLOR_BGRA2YUV_I420 conversion) the video output color is same as the array of images, but on real android devices the color output is completely different, so I've debugged and found out that my android devices color format is YUV420SP. Since there are no inbuilt opencv functions to convert RGBA/BGRA to YUV420SP, I've converted image to YUV_YV12 and then to YUV420SP/NV21 using the below code

```
public byte[] YV12toNV21(final byte[] input, final int width, final int height) {

        byte[] output = input;

        final int size = width * height;
        final int quarter = size / 4;
        final int vPosition = size; // This is where V starts
        final int uPosition = size + quarter; // This is where U starts

        System.arraycopy(input, 0, output, 0, size); // Y is same

        for (int i = 0; i < quarter; i++) {
            output[size + i*2 ] = input[vPosition + i]; // For NV21, V first
            output[size + i*2 + 1] = input[uPosition + i]; // For Nv21, U second
        }
        return output;
    }
```

But still I'm facing the same issue.

This is the Original RGBA Picture
[image: This is the Original RGBA Picture]

This one is the output of video
[image: This one is the output of video]

UPDATE:

After swapping U and V
[image]

Comment: Hello Stephen, i don't have an answer for your question, but whenever i had to do color format conversion i used [libyuv](https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv/). There should be methods for almost every conversion regarding YUV. ARGBToNV21 can be found in [convert_from_argb.h](https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv/+/master/include/libyuv/convert_from_argb.h)

Comment: @ChrisBe thanks for your insights, I'm able to integrate libyuv to my project, but have no luck running it. I'm facing shared objects linking problem. [Libyuv Implementation that I've used ](https://github.com/xiaoxiaoqingyi/libyuv-android). I'm expecting a simple fix. I'm afriad the method you proposed might complicate a little bit like compiling the lib from scratch which make the application a bit hefty considering the trade offs.

Comment: "my android devices color format is YUV420SP", you mean the codec output color is YUV420SP?

Comment: @E.Abdel. Yes, the color format supported by codec on my device.

Comment: Did you tried by switching U and V? on the secend picture it seems to be a U and V order problem

Comment: @E.Abdel I've Updated the post swapping U and V.